# Adding multiple labels to div (C#)

Tags: c#, webforms, label

I have a web forms project in Visual Studio, and I'm trying to add labels programmatically do a div called divLabels:

```
protected void addLabel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label testLabel = new Label();
    testLabel.Text = "test label";
    divLabels.Controls.Add(teste);
}
```

Everytime I change the value of a dropdownlist, this above method is called.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="listaClientes" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="addLabel" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

The first time I change the value of the dropdownlist, the label is created successfully. However, after the first time, no other labels are created. It only works the first time. I checked to see if the reason why I don't see the other labels is because they're being created on top of each other, but that's not it. Chrome's developer tools shows the page's html with only one label.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the Dropdownlist inside the UpdatePanel with **asynchronous postback**:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="listaClientes" runat="server" ClientMode="Static" OnSelectedIndexChanged="addLabel" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="listaClientes" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```